# ODE Event Location in python

Tags: python, ode

Is there any similar function in python to ODE Event Location function? For example, how can I write a code similar to

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = event(~,x)
value = x(1);     % detect x(1)=0
isterminal = true;   % Stop the integration
direction = -1;    % positive direction=1, negative =-1, all=0
```

I mean I want to detect the time at which a bouncing ball hit the ground and then it jumps back . At that time initial conditions change.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation of `solve_ivp`. I think the bouncing ball is even an example there.

The equivalent is

```py
def event(t,x): return x[0]
event.terminal=True
event.direction=-1
```

The difference is in multiple events, where matlab can use one vector valued event function, solve_ivp uses a vector of scalar valued functions.